# simplest way to send raw Byte-arrays using Ruby's TCPSocket-Class

Tags: ruby, network-programming, arrays, tcp

i want to send raw bytes using Rubys TCPSocket-Class. 
Has someone a good example?

I've tried it in this way, but it does not work :(

```
require 'socket'

host = '192.168.0.80'
port = 102
s = TCPSocket.new(host, port)

    s.write [0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x16,
             0x11, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
             0x01, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x02, 0x02, 
             0x02, 0xC2, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 
             0xC0, 0x01, 0x0A ].pack('C')
    puts s.read
    s.close

puts "exit"
```

thanks :)

Comment: first: its s.write instead of s.send, sorry... i don't know what exactly is going wrong, but it seems so that the write-method converts my byte-array into a string.

Comment: I edited the post for you, but in future please correct it yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a "*" after the format directive to eat all the elements in the list:

```
s.write [0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x16,
         0x11, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
         0x01, 0x00, 0xC1, 0x02, 0x02, 
         0x02, 0xC2, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 
         0xC0, 0x01, 0x0A ].pack('C*')
```

There are lots of neat tricks possible with string#format so it's worth studying [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack).