# Respond to FM1100 GPS device with ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, binary, gps

Teletonika FM1100 first sends the IMEI which you have to respond to by sending an acknowledgment packet 01 to. I can't figure out how i need to send that. It just keeps sending the IMEI because it does not get the 01 in the format it wants it i guess.

Here is a link to the Teletokina protocol documentation PDF http://bit.ly/1OrmI9P (Page 7, Server communication)

This is my code

```
require 'socket'                # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.new 1337   # Socket to listen on port
loop do
  Thread.new(server.accept) do |client|
    client.print "\x00\x01" # also tried "\x01"
    print "#{Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')}: #{client.read} \n"
    client.close
  end
end
```

I also tried it with `client.write` and `pack` in 4 different ways

```
...
client.write [0x01].pack('C')

client.write [0x00, 0x1].pack('C*')

client.write [0x01].pack('N')

client.write [0x00, 0x1].pack('N*')
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simplest way to send raw Byte-arrays using Ruby's TCPSocket-Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326424/simplest-way-to-send-raw-byte-arrays-using-rubys-tcpsocket-class)

Comment: @Drazen I ran into the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: I stopped working on the project for other reasons and never got to solving it sorry